# report() function in program to remove duplicates from an array

Tags: c++, cout

Hi I am looking for how to fix the problem in report function in program a to remove duplicates from an array.  the problem in the function report, if you take it out and you put the cout in main it will work fine but you give it a function and it will stop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void report (int s);

int main()
{
  int size = 10;
  int num[10];


  /*PROMPT USER TO INPUT 10 NUMBERS*/
  cout << "Please enter 10 integers, hitting return after each one: " << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    cin >> num[i];
  }


  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    for(int j=i+1;j<size;)
    {
      if(num[j]==num[i])
      {
        for(int k=j;k<size;k++)
          num[k]=num[k+1];

          size--;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
    }

    report(size,num[i]);

    return 0;
  }


  void report (int size, int[])
  {
    cout << "You entered " << size << " distinct numbers:  " ;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    cout << num[i] << "  ";
  }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Also please add the compiler error(s) you're getting and tell us what you don't understand about them.

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype is wrong:

```
void report (int size);                  // Wrong; missing the second int[] parameter

void report (int size, int[] int_array); // Right

int main()
{
  // ..
}

void report (int size, int[] int_array) {
  // ..
}
```